# PHP upload errors

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I have an upload script that's causing me some problems and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Here's the php code:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('uploads');

if (isset($_FILES["file"]["type"]) && isset($_FILES["file"]["size"])) {
if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 500120) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["error"];
        } else {                         
            if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
               echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO uploads (name) VALUES ('$name')");                 
                if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['desc'])) {
                    $title = $_POST['title'];
                    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO uploads (title, desc) VALUES ('$title', '$desc')");
                    echo $title;
                    echo $desc;
                }                  
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "File is too big";
    }
} else {
   echo "Wrong file type";
}
}
```

I know that my file paths and form input are correct and if I echo the `$title` or `$desc` variables they return with the correct values. My problem is this: for some reason it won't enter the `$title` and `$desc` values into the database. The first mysql query works fine but not the second. Any idea why?

Comment: surely you want to associate title, desc with the name ?

Comment: What's the output if you add `echo mysql_error()` after the second query?

Comment: yeah, it's a little screwed up right now but $name is for the actual file name, $title is for the user defined image name and $desc is for the user defined description.

Comment: First off, you really need to look at sanitizing data before you send it to the database, secondly what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an errors just nothing is entered into the database

Comment: **Bad**: Do not trust the `['type']` data - it's user-provided and can faked. **Worse** Check the error field FIRST before doing anything - you're checking it 4th. **VERY UGLY** Not checking for error conditions on your database calls, assuming they succeed. **HORRIBLE** You're using the user-provided filename which can be hacked and allow a malicious user to overwrite any file on your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because `desc` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), and it must be enclosed in backquotes in your query statement. Always check `mysql_error()` to find the cause of a failed query.

```
$success = mysql_query("INSERT INTO uploads (title, `desc`) VALUES ('$title', '$desc')");
if (!$success) echo mysql_error();
```

Please also escape `$title` and `$desc` before insert, as they are coming directly from `$_POST`.

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);
```

And do the same for `$name` in the earlier query:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: would this affect the $title variable too?

Comment: @codedude No it wouldn't affect `title` because that isn't a MySQL reserved word. See the list I just linked into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 2 records in the uploads table, for 1 file. Probably the name column is set to not null, and this causes second query not to work.
It have to be:

```
$name = mysql_escape_string($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$title = isset($_POST['title'])?mysql_escape_string($_POST['title']) : '';

$desc = isset($_POST['desc'])?mysql_escape_string($_POST['title']) : '';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO uploads (`name`, `title`, `desc`) VALUES ('$name', $title, $desc)");
```